# Difference between two sets containing the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen this example in a textbook.

Let $A = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\} \}$ and $B = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$.
Then $A - B = \{\{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$.

I was wondering, since the empty set is a subset of every set, shouldn't it still be in $A - B$, so $A - B = \{ \emptyset, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Empty set is a subset of every set; but it is not an element of every set.

Answer (score 1):

$A \setminus B$ is defined as $x \in A \land x \notin B$ so you should remove also $\emptyset$ which, in your case, is element in both.